# Syntax error in MySQL LIMIT clause

Tags: mysql, sql-limit

I'm having a problem with a query:

```
$sth = $Db->dbh->prepare(
   "SELECT * 
   FROM loader 
   WHERE download = 0 
    AND lastconnected BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND NOW() 
   ORDER BY lastconnected DESC 
   LIMIT :amount");
```

The LIMIT isn't working for some reason, if I change :amount to a hardcoded number it'll work but as soon as I use it as :amount it's giving me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''1'' at line 5
```

This is what I'm using to execute the prepared query:

```
$sth->execute(array(':amount' => $amount));
```

Been trying to figure it out for a couple of hours now. Hopefully someone can see something I'm not.

Comment: Is this putting single quotes around the amount? That might cause the problem.

Comment: Obvious questions: what language are you writing this in? Have you tried printing ":amount" to see if it has a valid value?

Comment: what is the value of $amount? please assign here your Amount variable..

Comment: The value of amount is also in the error use near ''1'' at line 5 the value of amount is 1. So it's picking up amount but for some reason putting 2 qoutes around it? Also the langauge is PHP

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a variable `LIMIT` with PDO, you have to bind each parameter with [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and explicitly specify that the parameter's value has integer type (`PDO::PARAM_INT`). `PDOStatement::execute()` with an array of input parameter values treats all values as strings (`PDO::PARAM_STR`), not the actual PHP types, as does calling `PDOStatement::bindParam()` without a type, but MySQL's `LIMIT` keyword does not take a string argument. This is documented in [the manual page for the method `PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), and there's an open [feature request to change the behavior](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44639).

Comment: Tepples, so I can't pass intergers in the array?

Comment: @user2879055 Pass the integer through `bindParam()` instead of the array.

Comment: I made it into 
    

`
$sth = $Db->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM loader WHERE download = 0 AND                lastconnected BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)            AND NOW()            ORDER BY lastconnected DESC            LIMIT :amount");

$sth->bindParam(':amount',$amount);
$sth->execute();
`

But it's still giving me the exact same error.

Comment: @user2879055 `$sth->bindParam(':amount',$amount)` means `$sth->bindParam(':amount',$amount,PDO::PARAM_STR)`. Specify a type if you don't want PDO to treat it as a string.

Comment: Made the bindParam into this now: 
`$sth->bindParam(':amount', $amount, PDO::PARAM_INT);` 
But still having the same results.